# Determine which web server is being used

Tags: asp.net

I have a web app (ASP.net with VB.net) that will run on one of three web servers.  I would like to know, at run time, which web server the app is on.  How can I determine which web server the app is on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.Environment.MachineName should get the name of the webserver for you.

Comment: I found that Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME").ToString works the best.

Comment: The main problem with  Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") is that in load balanced scenarios, this will not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to set environment variables in your webservers config/virtual hosts.

Well that is the common practice for apache/php applications. but it should be pretty much the same in commercial windows environments. only called differently and infinetly times more expensive.